# Issue with Infinite zoom on SVG

Tags: d3.js, svg

In the following example if you continue to zoom into location (6.5,10) at some point the lines stop drawing. Is there a solution for this issue?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgZZJb

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: I think the value inside the d attribute of the line becomes so large that svg does not show it. pre zooming it is `M-6364.339584532831,952.214549918316L` post zooming too far it becomes..
`M-371776390.3300619,39470020.68347957L ..` i think you should restrict infinite zooming.

Comment: I bet this has nothing to do with D3, but simply with the floating-point number user agents use to store the path's coordinates system and draw it. Let's wait for Robert Longson's opinion on this.

Comment: Gerardo is correct. Although the SVG specification highly recommends renderers use double precision floating point, they generally don't. That's due to technical reasons related to rendering engines, GPUs etc.  And it is easier than you might think to reach the limits of single precision arithmetic.

Comment: unfortunately restricting infinite zooming is not an option.